# MySQL Reservation Query ,

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
|| *id* || *calendar_type* || *event_name* || *event_details* || *start_date* || *end_date* || *closed_date* || *time_start* || *time_end* ||
|| 1 || OPEN || AVAILABLE BLOCK || _NULL_ || 2013-01-01 || 2013-12-31 || 0000-00-00 || 08:00:00 || 08:59:00 ||
|| 2 || OPEN || AVAILABLE BLOCK || _NULL_ || 2013-01-01 || 2013-12-31 || _NULL_ || 09:00:00 || 09:59:00 ||
|| 3 || OPEN || AVAILABLE BLOCK || _NULL_ || 2013-01-01 || 2013-12-31 || _NULL_ || 10:00:00 || 10:59:00 ||
|| 4 || OPEN || AVAILABLE BLOCK || _NULL_ || 2013-01-01 || 2013-12-31 || _NULL_ || 13:00:00 || 13:59:00 ||
```

and an Appointment_Calendar Table: Which holds the dates and times of what blocks of time are available, and those that are closed.

```
|| *id* || *start_time* || *duration_min* || *customer_id* || *consignee* || *trucker_name* || *email* || *phone* || *pallet_total* || *freight_type* || *notes* || *reserved_on* || *is_cancelled* ||
|| 1 || 2013-01-22 09:00:00 || 01:00:00 || 0 ||  || Testing ||  ||  || 20 || DELIVERY || this is a test || 2013-01-22 19:15:06 || 0 ||
|| 2 || 2013-01-22 10:00:00 || 01:00:00 || 0 ||  || Trucker 2 ||   ||  || 12 || DELIVERY ||  || 2013-01-22 19:16:37 || 0 ||
|| 4 || 2013-01-23 08:00:00 || 01:00:00 || 0 ||  || Trucker 3 ||  ||  || 10 || DELIVERY ||  || 2013-01-22 20:32:18 || 0 ||
```

Now my goal is to write one query (maybe two) that gets a list of all the available blocks (from appointment_calendar ) and returns just those times that are not in appointments (not reserved) or not closed for a particular date. The SQL below does this but when I introduce a Subquery to omit all the appointment dates or times see commented out segment, all the available appointment_calendar blocks dissapear . I was hoping to only have the available time blocks show

```
SELECT DATE('2013-01-23 08:00:00')as today,appointment_calendar.*
FROM appointment_calendar 
WHERE calendar_type='OPEN'
AND
 DATE( '2013-01-23 08:00:00') BETWEEN start_date AND end_date
AND
 DATE( '2013-01-23 08:00:00') 
  NOT IN (SELECT closed_date  FROM appointment_calendar WHERE calendar_type='CLOSED')

/*  This does not work somehow if the time is in the appointment all blocks for that day do not appear
AND
( TIMESTAMP('2013-01-23 08:00:00')  
    NOT IN  (SELECT TIMESTAMP( start_time) FROM appointments )
)
*/
```

Any suggested approaches?

Answer (score 0):

The part that is commented out will always evaluate to either true or false. So its going to either filter out all rows, or no rows. You need to somehow replace ' TIMESTAMP('2013-01-23 08:00:00')' with a timestamp from the appointment_calendar table. Maybe make a timestamp based on start_date and time_start?